# Oxygen25 MIDI keyboard won't work with Pro Tools 9

Tags: macbook-pro, midi, logic

I have Pro Tools 9.0.2 and a third Gen Oxygen25 MIDI keyboard connected by USB. Both are made by Avid, yet I can't get them to work together.

The keyboard even works with Logic Pro 9, just not Pro Tools 9.

I'm running OS X 10.6.8 on a MacBook Pro (15-inch).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Send to oxygen 25 also it should work

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the technical support people at both Avid/M-Audio and at Avid/Pro Tools (and unfortunately, in my experience, even though both companies are now owned by Avid, those divisions don't talk to each other much).

This is not the sort of problem that you can easily troubleshoot in a discussion forum like this one.

One thing that the tech support people at Avid will ask you: Did this combination of hardware and software ever work correctly, and now it is not working? Or have you never been able to use these together successfully?

Comment: I might add that just in the last three months Avid has laid off a great deal of their staff, including in the tech support department. Getting support from them for any of their products is much harder now.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Peripherals" setup on Pro Tools, you have the ***Send to*** setup wrong.  That is also supposed to point to your device.  (That is the **MIDI send** for the 8 channels in what you are assigning here as "controller 1."

**Send to should be also set to Oxygen 25**.

This is a fairly common error in Pro Tools and other DAWs.  After correcting this, maybe also trying other usb cables; and restarting your entire system, it should work.  You may also need to get a powered USB hub for consistent performance of music devices, especially since you are on a laptop.  I've seen that exact error and solved it by using powered USB hubs, fixing the basic settings, or replacing usb cables.